# jQuery closest() not working

Tags: jquery

I have an AJAX method that deletes a row from a database from a list of results from the database. Once the row has been successfully deleted, I want jQuery to fade out that row from the page.

After clicking on the delete button, the row is successfully deleted from the database, but the list item that is the parent of the button that was clicked does not fade out when searching for it using closest().

Here is my DOM:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="two columns alpha">
        </div>
        <div class="ten columns">
            <ul>
                <li><p></p></li>
                <li><p></p></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="admin_buttons">
            <div class="two columns">
                <button type="submit" class="admin_button edit_event">Edit</button>
            </div>
            <div class="two columns omega">
                <button type="submit" value="5" class="admin_button delete_event">Delete</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here is the jQuery:

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete_event', function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'php/deleteEvent.php',
        cache: false,
        data: {
            id: $(this).val()
        },
        success: function(data) {
            if(data === 'Error') {
                alert('Error: event not deleted.');
            }
            else
            {
                $(this).closest("li").fadeOut('slow');
            }
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: In the `success` callback, put `console.log(this)` and see what it logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it isn't working as you expect is because the `this` you get inside the `success` callback is **not** the `this` you have inside the click handler.

`.ajax()` has a `context` option for setting what gets passed to the `success` callback as `this`. You can use that:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    ...
    context: $(this), // set what 'this' will be inside the callback.
    ...
    success: function(data) {
        ...
        // this refers to what we set for context
        this.closest("li").fadeOut('slow'); 
        ...
    }
});
```